# Rails: <br> is not working in my view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, erb

I have to apologize that I ask a simple question.

It's hard to extract part of my code, because I don't know where is wrong.

Here is my `index.html.erb`
http://pastie.org/10337500#71-79

The question is that I want to add some space between two `div`.
Then, I add lots of `<br>` there, but it seems not work.

[image]

Comment: Hi Coda, you will need to add your code directly to the question, and then your question can be re-opened. For more info on asking, see the Help Center!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating CSS spacing widgets

There are a lot of ways to resolve this but it looks like you are doing an app with pages with different sections that will require layout with custom spacing.

A simple and flexible approach is to create graphical spacers in CSS. An example with a few ideas.

In your assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss

```
.gfx_mt_10 {
  margin-top:10px;
}

.gfx_margins_my_x_section {
  margin: 25px 25px 10px 10px ; /* Top Right Bottom Left */
}
```

In your html

```
<div class="gfx_mt_10">
  <p>Everything in here is the section with a margin of 10 pixels at the top.</p>      
</div>

<div class="gfx_my_x_section">
  <p>Everything in here is the section with a margin of 25 pixels at the top.</p>      
</div>

<div class="clearfix gfx_mt_10">
  <p>Everything in here is the section which combines clearfix attributes + a margin of 10 pixels at the top.</p>      
</div>
```

If you create CCS spacers like these graphical widgets, then you can use them in any class tag. I would not recommend changing a global like clearfix, that may have unintended consequences throughout your app.

### W3 CSS Documentation

I highly recommend, if you haven't already, reading up on the powers of CSS in the official resource [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/).

### Or use Bootstrap grid system

I should add, the work is done for you if you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) There is a learning curve, but it creates a framework for your UI that is platform flexible.

Comment: Thanks, I will try more by `boostrap`, because `margin` doesn't fit in mobile view.

Comment: Good idea. Bootstrap will give you a lot of formatting options. Also it will give you Glyphicons, buttons and menus. At first it may be counter-intuitive to use, but I hope you'll find it useful for making your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try `</br>` , and if that doesn't work it's probably because you have some unclosed tag somewhere along your code. If you don't, then just add a margin-bottom to the button or a margin-top to the img container.

Comment: `</br>` doesn't work, I am trying to find unclosed tag.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to add mounts of `<br> in the view layer. You'd better to use`padding`or`margin`. For example, try change:

```
<div class="clearfix">
```

to

```
<div class="clearfix", style="margin-top: 50px">
```

Comment: I know, I am curious why it doesn't work, but thanks. It works perfectly.